# Should I release self.view?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, release-management, retaincount

I have a question regarding to self.view in a UIViewController.

First, in my app, everything is created programmatically. And normally I create self.view in the loadView method:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:SCREEN_FRAME]autorelease]; // SCREEN_FRAME is a constant
```

At this moment, the retain count of self.view is 1.

So, my question is, do I have to release self.view when I'm done with the view controller? If so, where should I release it?

Thanks very much in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is being done for you by the implementation of UIViewController, just make sure you call `[super dealloc]` in your dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

self.view is added autorelease pool and object will be release when pool is released. you don't need to release explicitly. 
If you add object to pool and release manually you will get exception double dealloc (since object is getting released twice)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the reference of whoever might read this, the above answer is not exactly correct. self.view is called alloc, retain and autorelease, for the total retain count of 1. The retain call comes from the retain property and the dot syntax.

Therefore it DOES need to be released, but as willcodejavaforfood points out, the super implementation of dealloc does that.

Thanks